# How to use solr with existing web application

Tags: solr

Is there any way to embed solr with my existing web application, which needs to index the data incoming from my application? I need to use the search inside the application.

Is there any way to use solr without hosting it separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Solrj with [EmbeddedSolrServer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#EmbeddedSolrServer) implementation.

Comment: People looking this may want to check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110022/is-usage-of-embeddedsolrserver-now-outdated-not-recommended